# What is a better buy? The AMD RYZEN 7 4700U or 5700U?

Tags: processor, intel

i want to buy a laptop.
Both have 16GB RAM and the READON as graphics card.
What is a better buy?

**`4700U VS 5700U?`**

Answer (score 2):

The 5700u is a faster, less power consuming chip. In a vacuum the 5700u would be better 100% of the time.

However if one laptop has single channel memory and the other dual channel, or if there is a difference in components like the storage, screen or other items. It might be advantageous to buy the 4700u.Giving up in some basic cpu power, but gaining any other benefits.